# how to make indian chilly chicken

Tags: chicken

how to prepare Chilly Chicken. Its basically an indian recepie. Its my favourite dishes too. Please help me to make chilly chicken.

I ever prefer home based food. So please tell the masala preparation too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but recipe requests are off topic, see the [faq]. If you have specific problems following a recipe you already have, you are free to ask a concrete question about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chicken 500gram(prefer boneless chicken)
Gram flour 100 gram
corn flour 50gram
garlic ginger paste 1 tbsp
salt
water
curd 1/2cup
lemon 1 tbsp
turmeric powder 1/2 tbsp
```

combine altogether as above mentioned and make paste apply in the chicken. Make wet for half an hour. Heat the oil in tawa and make a deep fry then chilly chicken is ready serve with sliced onion.